# Regular Expression to replace if (,,) with ternary operator ?:

Tags: regex, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have a xml file in the following format

```
<Function>
    <Name>BoxedClip</Name>
    <Instance>CalculateFormula</Instance>
    <Formula>if((ELIGIBLE_SHORT_QTY > 0),-1*min(LONG_QTY ,(-1 * SHORT_QTY)) * DIV_AMOUNT *  (if ((ELIGIBLE_SHORT_QTY != 0), DLR_TIMES_SHORT_QTY / ELIGIBLE_SHORT_QTY, 0) - if ((ELIGIBLE_LONG_QTY != 0), DLR_TIMES_LONG_QTY / ELIGIBLE_LONG_QTY, 0))/100,0)</Formula>
</Function>
<Function>
    <Name>ExcessBorrowClipUSD</Name>
    <Instance>CalculateFormula</Instance>
    <Formula>if(((-1*BORROW_QTY) >= (-1*SHORT_QTY)),(BORROW_QTY-SHORT_QTY)* DIV_AMOUNT_USD * (if ((ELIGIBLE_SHORT_QTY != 0), DLR_TIMES_SHORT_QTY / ELIGIBLE_SHORT_QTY, 0) - if ((ELIGIBLE_LONG_QTY != 0), DLR_TIMES_LONG_QTY / ELIGIBLE_LONG_QTY, 0)) / 100,0)</Formula>
</Function>
```

I need to recursively replace all the if conditions with ternary operator.

I came up with the following expression:
`if[^(]*\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,()]+)\)` replace with `($1?$2:$3)`

This works perfectly for all if clauses with no parenthesis in the else clause.

But for any if having parenthesis in the else clause, In the third remembered pattern above I need it to ignore all matching brackets and stop at the first mismatched closing bracket.

Comment: [See here](http://i.imgur.com/ls6Eygt.png), you *need* to tell us what regex flavor you're using.

Comment: I think it probably also wouldn't work if there was an embedded if in any part of the expression.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am not aware of the different types of regex expressions. 
I can open up the xml in Visual Studio/vim/textpad/notepad/notepad++. So a solution for any of the types is fine.
But the above expression is only working with Visual Studio as of now.
Also I tried some recursive patterns, but seems like they do not work in Visual Studio Search.

Comment: @VibhavRoy this is exactly the reason why you need to tell us the tool you're using. VS uses .NET regexes, Notepad++ uses boost::regex, VIM uses POSIX, etc etc. Those are different beasts.